# how to import java.security.* in my gwt application

Tags: java, gwt, jar, rsa, browser-plugin

i want to develop a plugin using gwt. It has to use java.security.* for the key generation on client side.
i have made all requirement
But it is showing following error.

> Loading modules
>
> coreservlets.GwtApp1
>
> ```
> Loading inherited module 'coreservlets.GwtApp1'
>     Loading inherited module 'java.security.KeyPair'
>        [ERROR] Unable to find 'java/security/KeyPair.gwt.xml' on your classpath; >could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
>     [ERROR] Line 15: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
> ```

i have inherited all the related class  like "java.security.KeyPair" in my gwtapp1.gwt.xml file

also i included jar in  classpath itself.but still the error has not gone.
what should i do.plz suggest
here is my java code

```
package coreservlets.client;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;


public class Keygen {

private PrivateKey privKey;
private PublicKey pubKey;
private static Keygen keygen = null;

private Keygen() {

}

public static Keygen getInstance() {

    if (keygen == null) {
        keygen = new Keygen();
    }

    return keygen;
}

public void KeyGenerator(String ALGORITHAM) {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = null;
    SecureRandom random = null;
    try {
        keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHAM);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
        //random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    //keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
    keyGen.initialize(1024);
    KeyPair key = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
    privKey = key.getPrivate();
    pubKey = key.getPublic();

}

public String getPubKeyasString() {
    //return Base64.encodeBase64String(pubKey.getEncoded());
    try {
        return new String(pubKey.getEncoded(),"ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
public String getPriKeyasString() {
    //return Base64.encodeBase64String(privKey.getEncoded());
    try {
        return new String(privKey.getEncoded(),"ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: It seems to be something wrong with your 'KeyPair.gwt.xml'. Check everything is correct or paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

For key generation you can use the [gwt-crypto](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/) library, but be prepared to certain performance issues and unsupported features.

[Edit]
Some time ago, I did success wrapping a pure js rsa solution using jsni. The js I took was the [jsbn.js](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) library

Comment: thanks for suggestion but i dont have to use gwt-chrypto lib.do you have any other possible way to sort it out.

Comment: Unfortunately java.security is not emulated in gwt-jre, so you would not be able to use those classes although you created a module including the original java files (from sun/oracle). I have edited my response to include a jsni possible solution.

Comment: that can be my option too.On the whole what i have to do is i have to develop browser plugin which on installation will generate keys on client side and public key will be send to server which will encrypt the file and that encrypted file will be decrypted by my private key on client side.one possible way i am doing is generating keys using gwt in that above problem is occuring.so i need suggestion what i should do,also is their any other way to generate public key which should work on server side algo,as its not working by generating keys using js.i am new to gwt.thanks again for your reply.

Comment: keys generated with jsbn should work in server side using openssl, so I guess that you can use javax.security in server since it is compatible with openssl. Before wrapping jsbn you can play with the demo page in theirs site (http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/rsa.html) generating keys and messages and trying to decrypt/encrypt with your server java implementation. Once you have that working, you can work in client wrapping the js methods you needed

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino Could you please help me with this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25777287/how-do-i-use-rsa-between-server-and-gwt-client

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino Do you use jsbn.js with a gwt-crypto backend?

Comment: Yes finally I used jsbn in my project without lib-crypto because I had to create keys in client side. In server side I used bouncycastle. If your keys are generated in server, you could use lib-crypto I did succeeded in my research. This was a couple of years ago though.

Answer (score 0):

In a `.gwt.xml` file `<inherits ...>` refers to another `.gwt.xml` file. I suspect that you have used it like a java `import ...` instead?

What you should do, if you want to use `java.security.KeyPair` clientside in GWT is to ascertain that the source is available to the GWT compiler. This is done using a `<source path="..."  />` entry in the `.gwt.xml` file.

You may want to visit the [GWT JRE Emulation Reference](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation) page, where sadly you will see that none of the `javax.*` packages are supported, so good luck with your project... Perhaps you should keep the code using `KeyPair` on the server side only?

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help, actually i am new to gwt.i have seen various examples of developing gwt app like [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/GWTModules/article.html) but unable to get how to use java.security.* jar.could you please explain me more about it.thanks again

Comment: The GWT compiler needs the source code for each and every class that goes in the client. You may be able to extract the `KeyPair` (and related/referenced classes!) from `src.zip` in your JDK and make that work.